# Screen Sharing in El Capitan – Gone?

Tags: macos, screen-sharing

When I upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan, I got a warning about Apple’s [Screen Sharing.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_Sharing) being not supported.

Sure enough, an alias to the app was moved to a folder named "Incompatible Software". When I run the app, it never connects to the server.

Is there some replacement for this functionality ([VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) screen sharing) bundled into El Capitan? Or did Apple really just drop this important feature?

Comment: Did you try going to Safari and type vnc://ip.of.machine in the URL bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's under `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Screen\ Sharing.app` here. You should still be able to call it directly (e.g. via Spotlight) or just use <kbd>Cmd-K</kbd> in Finder to initiate a VNC session (use `vnc:NAME-OF-REMOTE-SYSTEM` as address).

Comment: I don't know what caused the initial messages. Indeed launching that app or using the `vnc:` in `Finder` > `Go` > `Connect to Server` does indeed run the Screen Sharing app successfully.